# Python "with" statement for Selenium driver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, with-statement

A part of my script is scraping results from Selenium WebDriver and because my code is supposed to run forever (until I close it) I don't really have a way of implementing `driver.quit()` method. I tried doing this with a "with" statement but the driver just closes after `init_driver()` has been executed:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def init_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://www.lsbet.com/live')

    return driver

while True:
    with init_driver() as driver:
        ... # Do something
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can notably use [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) from the standard library to actually implement your `init_driver` function as a context manager.

For example, using the simplest way with `@contextlib.contextmanager` decorator, it could be something like :

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def init_driver(options, profile):
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver.exe')
        driver.get('https://www.lsbet.com/live')
        yield driver
    finally:
        # code to close/quit your driver
        pass
```

*(note the use of `yield` instead of `return`)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use a context manager.

```
class SeleniumManager:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        # Setup logic goes here...
        print('I have started...')

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        # Teardown logic goes here...
        print('I am finished...')

with SeleniumManager() as sm:
    # Your logic here...
    print('I am working on something...')
```

After your logic under the with statement is finished, the context manager will automatically call the **exit**() method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
with init_driver() as driver:
    while True:
        #...Do stuff
        if condition == False:
            driver.quit()
            break
```